# gzdeflate from PHP to iPhone

Tags: objective-c, compression, zlib

I have a problem with compression. Maybe you can help me. When I try to compress data in PHP and uncompress it in Objective-C, it doesn't work.

This is what I do:

PHP

```
$text = gzdeflate('alexander');
$text = base64_encode($text);
echo $text;
exit();
```

iOS

```
NSMutableData *decoder = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"S8xJrUjMS0ktAgA="];
NSData *data4 = [decoder gzipInflate];
NSLog(@"%@",data4);
```

CONSOLE: (null)

- I did check the result of base64 and it is correct.
- zlib framework is added
- `#include <zlib.h>` added in header

[Source for gzipInflate](https://github.com/geoffgarside/cocoagit/blob/master/Source/Categories/NSData+Compression.m)

Comment: Are you fetching the data from the web? I believe it can be done with zero effort as part of the process by using either standard NSUrlRequest or ASIHTTPRequest